# dynamically add input field according result

Tags: php, input, dynamic

I need to know how to add dynamically of similar input fields if the value of the sum is > 0.

Let me explain, I have a list of users in a program and each user decide if he/she paid a single payment or in installments, so here is the problem I have, if the number of installments is per example 2 or 10 how can I add input field to show how many installments left to pay for the subscription in each user with installments.

I have this rows:

```
$honorario // is the total amount per subscription (4000.00)
$nCuotas // is the number of installments to paid a total amount (10)
$cantPagar // is the value of each installment for every month (400.00)
$fPago // is for single payment or if the user will pay for installments (1 for single, 2 for installment)
```

So if the user choose single payment the form with number of installments left to pay will not show it BUT if the user choose installments when he/she login the program he/she will see the form with the quantity of input field left to pay

Here an example code:

```
<?php if($fPago != '1') { ?>
<?php  if($nCuotas >= '1') { ?> // Here I think need something like $i = $nCoutas to show equal form like a nCuotas the user have
<form name="statusPago" id="statusPago" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<input id="pago" name="pago" type="text" placeholder="100" value="" class="form-control" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
<input type="hidden" name="idCaso" value="<?php echo $idCaso; ?>">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?= trans('save'); ?>" />
<input type="reset" class="btn" value="<?= trans('reset'); ?>" />
</div>
</form>
<div id="loadStatus" style="display:none;"><img src="images/loading.gif" /></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
<?php if($fPago != '1') { ?>
    <?php  if($nCuotas >= '1') { ?> // Here I think need something like $i = $nCoutas to show equal form like a nCuotas the user have
        <form name="statusPago" id="statusPago" method="post">

            <?php for($i=0; $i< $nCuotas; $i++){ ?>


            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="pago" name="pago[]" type="text" placeholder="100" value="" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="hidden" name="idCaso[]" value="<?php echo $idCaso; ?>">
                <?php } ?>

                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <input type="reset" class="btn"  />
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="loadStatus" style="display:none;"><img src="images/loading.gif" /></div>

    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

You can `var_dump($_POST['pago']);` and `var_dump($_POST['idCaso']);` for form values.